# Using a Windows executable within a Ruby gem

Tags: ruby, exe

I'm looking to include a Windows .exe in my gem and call on that executable from within the gem. All the suggestions I've seen for including executable in gems calls for a hashbang to indicate which program should run the executable (typically "#!/usr/bin/env ruby
"). I don't know of any program to call; I simply want to call the .exe. What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hashbang can make a gem executable but isn't necessary to simply call the .exe within the gem itself. The calling module was in the gem's lib/ and the .exe in bin/. I was able to call the .exe from the ruby code with

```
exe_path = File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "..", "bin", "foo.exe"))
return_value = `#{exe_path}`
```

This works as long as you copy both lib/ and bin/ in the gemspec.

Answer (score 1):

Those are for *nix systems.

You can do

```
%x{full path to your .exe}
```

Use

```
$?
```

to get the exit status.

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html

Comment: Is there a way to refer to the executable within the gem via a relative path?

Comment: Relative to what?  You can try calling it relative to your working dir.  Or you can make sure it is in your path and call it directly.

Comment: If I'm including foo.exe in the gem, is there a relative path from the wherever the command %x{path\to\foo.exe} executes (the working directory?) to stored-in-the-gem foo? Or is what I want not possible?